# Minimize Chernoff Bound Exponential Distribution

Tags: moment-generating-functions, exponential-distribution

For the distribution $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \ \ x =[0,\infty]$ I am trying to understand how to utilize the Chernoff Bound. The Chernoff bound is:
$P(X>x) \leq g_X(r)e^{-rx}$ where $g_X(r)$ is the moment generating function for the distribution. I have the moment generating function as $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - r}$. This makes the Chernoff bound $P(X>x) \leq \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - r}e^{-rx}$.

The question is asking which value of r returns the tightest bound ie minimize the Chernoff bound over all possible values of r. From graphing various combinations of lambda and r it seems that have an r value as close to lambda as possible but I am not sure. Having an r value as close to lambda as possible results in steep exponential. However, having a r value of 1 results in a function that starts closer to zero but takes longer to reach zero. What does "tighter" bound mean, and how does having a tighter bound help with using the Chernoff bound?

The following question then asks to compare the Chernoff bound with the Markov bound with $\lambda = 1$. I am further confused because this would mean the only value of r allowed is 0. Have I calculated the Chernoff bound incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several common notions of tightness of bounds, below is perhaps the simplest one.

Denote the Chernoff bound as $B(x) \equiv \frac{ \lambda }{ \lambda - r} e^{- rx}$ for the exponential function, which tail probability (complement CDF)  is $P(X > x) = 1 - F_X(x) = e^{-\lambda x}$.

The error $B(x) - e^{-\lambda x}$ is readily shown to be always positive over $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ for all $0 < r < \lambda$.

Consider the total error over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, which is an routine integral:
\begin{align}
\Delta(r) \equiv \int_{ x = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{ \lambda }{ \lambda - r} e^{- r x} - e^{-\lambda x} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{ \lambda}{ r\, (\lambda - r)} - \frac1{\lambda}
\end{align}
Note that the relative error $(B(x) - e^{-\lambda x})/e^{-\lambda x}$ doesn't converge **as is**. You may consider various transformation to make it work if the notion of relative error is really important to you.

Moving on. One can already guess that the minimum of $\Delta(r)$ occurs at $r_0 = \lambda / 2$ in the middle because the function is mirror symmetric (exchange $r \longleftrightarrow \lambda-r$). Anyway, checking that with the first and second derivative of $\Delta(r)$ is routine.

As $r$ varies, the curve $B(x)$ may get closer or further to $P(X > x)$ point-wise at any given $x$, depending on the relation between $r$ and $\lambda$. As a whole, one may consider the $r = r_0 = \lambda / 2$, which minimizes $\Delta(r)$ as defined above, as producing the "tightest" bound.

Sometimes, depending on the applications, one might care only about a specific interval of $a < x < b$. One then optimizes $r$ by minimizing the corresponding error over that interval only. It will be a different $r_0$ for different situation.

BTW, here the error over $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ is minimized to $\min \{\Delta(r)\} = \Delta(\frac{\lambda}2) = 3/\lambda$.

---

If your so-called Markov bound refers to the common $P( X > x) < \frac{ E[X] }x$, then it is just $B_M(x) = \frac1{\lambda x}$.

Note that the Markov inequality is very loose and the corresponding error doesn't converge, as in it's basically $\int \frac1{x} dx$ that blows up.

The Markov bound as such is a simple function, and one can certainly compare the functional forms of the Chernoff bound $B(x)$ with $B_M(x)$, either in general, or for given $\lambda = 1$ and discuss the numerical details at specific points of $x$.

I'm afraid not much (or too much) can be said without further context.

Comment: Hello, Lee thank you for your answer, it is very good and helpful. Can I ask you, what does the variable r correspond to. I only know that different integer of r in the moment generating function, generate the $M_r$ moment. What does a fractional r "mean" for lack of a better word. If this is a different question and you don't want answer I understand.

Comment: The exercise was to prove the Chernoff bound using the Markov bound which is what you listed in your answer and then plot the two with r set to result in the tightest Chernoff bound.

Comment: It 's not the value of $r$ that gives the $k$-th moment, it is the coefficient of the $k$-th derivative [evaluated at zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Calculations_of_moments).